# AUTHENTICATION REQUIRED: An application wants access to the keyring "Default Keyring", but it is locked. Can I disable this?

Tags: password, settings, authentication, error-handling, keyrings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxmRG.png)

AUTHENTICATION REQUIRED: An application wants access to the keyring "Default Keyring", but it is locked. Can I disable this? It keeps popping u

Comment: Are you logging in without a password?

Comment: No, I use my password for logging in, but it doesn't work to unlock this.

Comment: Basically you need to unlock the keying at login. There are many questions on the site about this already.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-keyring/) is an article that explains Ubuntu keyring in detail.

It is possible that your login password and keyring password got out of sync. It could happen if you for example changed your login password using `passwd` command and not the GUI tool in Ubuntu.

You should probably change your keyring password to be the same as your login password.

The password change procedure, according to the linked article, is as follows:

**Change keyring password**

Suppose you changed your account password. Now when you login, your system tries to unlock the keyring automatically using the new login password. But the keyring still uses the old login password.

In such a case, you can change the keyring password to the new login password so that the keyring gets unlocked automatically as soon as you login to your system.

Open the Password and Keys application from the menu.

Now, right click on the Login keyring and click on Change Password.

**What if you don’t remember the old login password?**

You probably know that it is easy to reset forgotten password in Ubuntu. The problem comes with the keyring in such cases. You changed the account password but you don’t remember the old account password that is still used by the keyring.

Now you cannot change it because you don’t know the old password. What to do now?

In such a case, you’ll have to remove the entire keyring itself. You can do that from the Passwords and Keys application (click "Delete").

It will ask for your confirmation.

Alternatively, you may also manually delete the keyring files in `~/.local/share/keyrings` directory.

When the old keyring is removed and you try to use Chrome/Chromium, it will ask you to create new keyring.

You can use the new login password so that the keyring gets unlocked automatically.

Comment: OP is not logging in automatically.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Maybe somehow his login password and keyring password got out of sync and he should change his keyring password to be the same as login password.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it.